# sql case when where limit 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused about why this happened?

```sql
select case when COUNT(1)> 0
           then remain_salary_money
           else 0
       end AS remainBorrowMoney
from  salary_pay_detail
where project_id = 483984364271566848 
    and team_id = 491297935619784704
    and DATE(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-01')) < '2020-11-01'
ORDER BY create_time desc
LIMIT 1
```

and another sql

```sql
select remain_salary_money
from salary_pay_detail
where project_id = 483984364271566848 
    and team_id = 491297935619784704
    and DATE(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-01')) < '2020-11-01'
ORDER BY create_time desc
LIMIT 1
```

I got **1948484** in the first sql result, **339220** is the second sql result .

you can image two records:

```
| month | remain_salary_money   | year | create_time|
| ----- | --------------------  | ---- | ---------- |
| 09    | 1948484               | 2020 | 2021-01-07 19:45:20|
| 10    | 339220                | 2020 | 2021-01-08 19:45:25 |
```

I want to know what happed ?

this is for test

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `month` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `money` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

insert sql

```sql
INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `month`, `year`, `money`, `create_time`) VALUES (1, 9, 2020, 1111, '2021-01-07 19:45:20');
INSERT INTO `test`(`id`, `month`, `year`, `money`, `create_time`) VALUES (2, 10, 2020, 2222, '2021-01-08 19:45:25');
```

test sql

```sql
select  money from test where DATE(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-01')) < '2020-11-01'
ORDER BY create_time desc
LIMIT 1;

select  case when COUNT(1)> 0
           then money
           else 0  end from test where DATE(CONCAT(`year`,'-',`month`,'-01')) < '2020-11-01'
ORDER BY create_time desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Apparently,I am wondering why **select case when count(1)>0...** can not return **339220**

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with this : `DATE(...) <= '2020-11-01'` versus `DATE(...) < '2020-11-01'` The first is lower or equal, the second is strictly lower. However, it's missing data sample to reproduce

Comment: I updated this post , my apologize

Comment: Create time is in 2021 is that a typo?

Comment: Your first query should not work.  It has an aggregation function in the `select` along with non-aggregated columns -- and no `group by` for them.  Broken SQL returns indeterminate results.

Comment: The first query is malformed. There's an aggregation function but no GROUP BY. This query can only run in MySQL, and even then, the result is unpredictable. Please fix the query, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aggregate function without a group by is over the whole set. What your query with the count returns is indeterminate..

Add in the fact that you are filtering by date and month but ordering(inconsistently) by createdtime then I cannot figure out what you are trying to do.

What were you trying to achieve?